# How to run code before all my methods inside controller in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-4, before-filter

I have Content controller with REST methods (index..create..store..) and i want to run some code before any of those methods run.

what i am trying to do is to set var for my layout with some data that is relevant to all my methods within Content controller:

```
$this->layout->myvar = 'some-data';
```

I tried to do something like that:

```
class ContentController extends BaseController {
    function __construct() {
        $this->layout->myvar= 'some-data';
    }
..
```

but it doesn't seems to work. 
i get "Attempt to assign property of non-object" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Laravel 5.1+

This has been deprecated in favour of Middleware.

### Laravel 4

You could set the `beforeFilter` like this:

```
class ContentController extends BaseController {
    function __construct() {
        // this function will run before every action in the controller
        $this->beforeFilter(function()
        {
            // this will make the variable $myvar available in your view
            $this->layout->with('myvar', 'some-data');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but i still get error "Attempt to assign property of non-object" when i try to set $this->layout->myvar = ...

Comment: i get similar error "Call to a member function with() on a non-object" - seems like the $this->layout maybe is not object but when i use it within the other functions in the controller then everything is good.

Comment: @Brightside OK. If it works in your actions, then maybe it's due to the layout being set at some point in your base controller. Try replacing `beforeFilter` function with `afterFilter` and see if that works for you. The after filter will of course be run after the actions, instead.

Comment: thanks! and yes the layout being set in my base controller. :)

Comment: `parent::__construct()` ??

Answer (score 4):

try share in app/routes.php

```
View::share('variable_name', 'value');
```

ex:

```
View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

will share variable with its value across all views